# Can't resolve all parameters for UserService:(Http, ?)

Tags: angular

My project was working fine until i upgraded to recent Angular2 version 2.0.0-beta.17

My UserService is like this

```ts
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BaseService } from './base.service';
import { SubDomain } from './../interfaces/subdomain.interface';
import { SubDomainService} from './index';

@Injectable()
export class UserService extends BaseService {
  subDomain: SubDomain;
  constructor(
    private _http: Http,
    private subDomainService: SubDomainService
  ) {
     super();
     this.subDomain = subDomainService.subDomain;
  } 
}
```

and SubDomainService is like this

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SubDomain } from './../interfaces/subdomain.interface';
import { CompanyService } from './company.service';

@Injectable()
export class SubDomainService {
  subDomain: SubDomain = {
    exists: false,
    is_sub_domain_url: false,
    sub_domain: '',
    company_id: '',
    user_id: '',
    name:''
  };

  constructor(
    private _companyService: CompanyService
  ) {
  }
}
```

I looked up for solutions but most of them were about making a service injectable but here i followed the same convention but stilll it's giving the error

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (Http, ?).

My AppModule is like this

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule } from './core.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './config/routes/index';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   routes,
   BrowserModule,
   CoreModule.forRoot()
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

CoreModule is like this

```ts
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  SubDomainService, 
  CompanyService, 
  UserService
} from './shared/services/index';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/modules/shared.module';

@NgModule({
   exports: [SharedModule]
})

export class CoreModule {
   static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: CoreModule,
        providers: [SubDomainService,UserService,CompanyService]
    };
   }

   constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
       if (parentModule) {
           throw new Error('CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be due to this import statement

```
import { SubDomainService} from './index';
```

you might be exporting SubDomainService from a different file i.e. index.ts in your case, **consider importing service directly from it's own file**.

Comment: I tried this while importing in my services and components and has resolved the issue but i am using it the same way in my modules like in core module.
This is quite confusing because the issue got resolved but we don't know the reason behind the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Devesh,

The problem is the following:

- You are importing from an index.ts file and the order in that file of the statements that you use to export the different services is wrong since at least one dependency is placed AFTER the other service that has it as such.

The solution:

- You could in your either in the module import the services from its direct file
- OR order the export statements in the index.ts file of the services folder in such a way that the ones that have dependencies are always after the exportation of its dependencies.

This is difficult to track since angular is just throwing an error in the console without mentioning this in details.

example for your case shared/services/index.ts

`export * from './sub-domain.service'
export * from './user.service`