# Can't resolve all parameters for UserServiceService: (?)

Tags: javascript, angular, get, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get users data by the link given in `getsUserUrl`.To do that
it requires a `token`(see the `token` variable) that I have added in the header. .Whenever I start the server I get an error like this.

```html
Can't resolve all parameters for UserServiceService: (?).at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
```

Here is my code. I don't know what parameter am I missing in Header.

```
import { Injectable,Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient ,HttpErrorResponse,HttpClientModule} 
from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Token } from '@angular/compiler';

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class UserServiceService {

  usersData: any[] = [];
  user:string

  getUserUrl="https://auth.openshift.io/api/search/users?q=rohit";
   token=`eysdsfdp.whsofd23.fdiu`;
   constructor(private httpclient:HttpClient) {
    }
     private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', err);
     return throwError(err.message || err);
    }
 searchUsers()
 {
    const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
    })
  }; 
     var res=this.httpclient.get(this.getUserUrl,httpOptions);
    return res.pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

 }
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.
**I'm attaching the code photo for your reference**
[image]

**As the person wanted my component code, I'm adding that too here**
[image]

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150120/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-userservicehttp

Comment: No That didn't helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place `authorization` keyword in quotes as well

```
const httpOptions = new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type':  'application/json',
'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
});
```

Or you can define it this way also

```
let httpOptions = new HttpHeaders();
httpOptions = httpOptions .set('h1', 'v1').set('h2','v2');
```

Comment: It's in the quotes only :/

Comment: New error:`Can't resolve all parameters for UserServiceService: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)`

Comment: check what i posted now

Comment: You are creating the new Httpheader as an object element which is causing the issue. You don't need to define it as a object element.

Comment: Can you post you component code from where you are calling this service?

Comment: Give me a second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181261/discussion-between-exterminator-and-rajat-singh).

Answer (score 1):

The Error messages `Can't resolve all parameters for UserServiceService: (?)` indicates that the angular DI can't find the `HttpClient` dependency, which is likely caused by you missing to import the `HttpClientModule` inside your `AppModule`.

To solve this add the `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http` to the `imports` section of your `AppModule`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line from your code

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And import the `HttpClientModule` in your module file. And declare into the `imports` array. LIke as following

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
   HttpClientModule
```

And remove the importing of the `HttpClientModule` in your services file

Comment: You don't need the `HttpModule` because `HttpClientModule` replaces it.